# how do I make a nav submenu reverse for last-child

Tags: css

I have a drop down nav and want to reverse the last child to stay on the page. How can I do this?

```
/* Sub Menu */
/* Drop Down Box BKGD  & STYLE*/
.menu ul {
    z-index:8000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left:0px;
    opacity: 0;
    background:url(../images/BKGDRepeat3_03.png);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 3px 5px #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0  3px 5px #666;
     box-shadow: 0  3px 5px #666;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px5px 5px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu ul:last-child {
    color:#C00;
    right:0px;
    left:auto;
}
```

html

```
<div style="clear:both" id="nav_bar"> 
<ul class="menu">

    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">one</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Directory</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul>
            <<li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>

        </ul>
     </li>

</ul> <!-- end .menu -->
</div>
```

this currently affects all the sub menus, not just the last one.

Comment: it would be better if had the html, but you could try nth-last-child(n) pseudo class instead if last-child doesnt work

Comment: try using `:last-of-type` instead of `:last-child`

Comment: nothing is working, I've added the html now

Comment: If you want to target the ul in the last li try `.menu li:last-child ul`

Comment: NICE, that did it.  Thanks,  how do I accept your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your html... Sounds like you need to be targeting the li, not the ul.

```
.menu ul li:last-child {
    color:#C00;
    right:0px;
    left:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
.menu ul:last-of-type {
    //
}
```

Assuming each ul is a submenu. otherwise you are looking to style the li.